# Proof that if $f,g : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ are measurable then $f g$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be the extended real line (i.e. including $\{\pm \infty\}$).

***Proposition:*** If  $f,g : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ are measurable then $f g$ is measurable (where $0 \cdot (\pm \infty)=0$).

***Proof:***

Let $h=fg$ so that $h: X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

If for all $E \subset X$ we have that $f(E) \neq 0$ when $g(E)= \pm \infty$ and $g(E) \neq 0$ when $f(E)= \pm \infty$ then $h$ is a continuous function of measurable functions, and is thus measurable.

For the more general case suppose $\exists E \subset X$ such that:

**(i)** $f(E)= 0$ when $g(E)= \pm \infty$,

*AND/OR*

**(ii)** $g(E)= 0$ when $f(E)= \pm \infty$.

Then by convention we have that $h(E)=0$. However:

$h(E)=0 \implies $ **(i)** or **(ii)** $\implies f^{-1}(0) = E \in \mathcal{M}$ or $g^{-1}(0) = E \in \mathcal{M}$ (since $f$ and $g$ are measurable).

Thus $h^{-1}(0)=E \in \mathcal{M}$, and thus $h$ is still measurable despite such a set $E$.

I am new to measure theory and am wondering if this is a valid proof of the proposition above? I know that if $f,g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable than $h$ would be measurable, and my strategy was to show that the addition of the points $\{ \pm \infty \}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ does not change the conclusion. Any comments on this would be much appreciated as I am trying to develop my skills with writing proofs.

Comment: Notice that $h^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(0) \cup g^{-1}(0)$. Otherwise, it is fine.

Comment: @user251257 Why is that true?

Comment: $h(x) = f(x)g(x) = 0$ iff $f(x) = 0$ or $g(x)=0$. That remains also true in $\bar{\mathbb R}$ with the convention $0\cdot \pm\infty = 0$.